# Show that $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How can I show $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is strictly convex? Can I use the fact that $x^2$ is strictly convex to prove this?

Additionally, is the function uniformly convex?

Edit: Although the second derivative of f(x) is always positive, is there any way to prove the convexity algebraically?

Comment: What does uniformly convex mean for a function?

Comment: I think the term strictly convex is a fairly **standard** one.

Comment: Fun fact: even though $x^2$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ are both strictly convex, $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ is not. (Looking at the graph, I think it's concave for $|x|\ge\sqrt3$.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the fact that $f$ is the Euclidean norm evaluated along a line excluding the origin.

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, you can show that for $u, v \in \mathbf{R}^n$, the triangle inequality $\lVert u + v \rVert_2 \leq \lVert u\rVert_2 + \lVert v\rVert_2 $ is strict unless $u = \kappa v$ for some $\kappa \in \mathbf{R}$.

Hence, we have that, for $\lambda \in (0, 1)$ and $x, y \in \mathbf{R}$,
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y)
&= \lVert \lambda (1, x) + (1 - \lambda)(1, y)\rVert_2 \\
&\leq \lvert\lambda\rvert \lVert(1, x)\rVert_2 + \lvert 1 - \lambda \rvert \lVert(1, y)\rVert_2 \\
&= \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(y),
\end{align*}
where the inequality is strict unles $\lambda(1, x) = \kappa(1 - \lambda)(1, y)$ for some $\kappa \in \mathbf{R}$.
But, equating the first entries of these vectors, this can only happen when $\lambda = \kappa(1 - \lambda)$ and so $x = y$.
Thus, $f$ is strictly convex.